# How to count the number of days between two dates in the column based on another column categories

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have some problem to create an new column in power bi with DAX. Here are my data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BR2pE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BR2pE.png)

I want to count the number of days between two dates in DATE Column based on the column LIB

The numbers of days between date(19/02/2022) when LIB=INI and the date(21/02/2022) when LIB=C FOR FIELD_ID=1
The numbers of days between date(19/02/2022) when LIB=INI and the date(22/02/2022) when LIB=B FOR FIELD_ID=1 and so , like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7J9G.png)

Can you help me please

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NUM_DAYS = 
VAR currFldID = [FIELD_ID] -- get the value from the current row.
                           -- You can get any other value like this 
                           -- from the current row to filter your table in 
                           -- CALCULATE() if you need that.
VAR currINIDate =
    CALCULATE(
        MAX(tbl[DATE]) -- to get scalar value MAX() was used. 
                       -- It is the last step while CALCULATE() prossed

        ,ALL() -- This is the first step of CALCULATE() 
               -- according to DAX rules.
               -- It opens all the table as it is.
 
        -- lets modify the table:
        ,tbl[LIB]="INI" -- the first filter
        ,tbl[FIELD_ID]=currFldID -- the second one
    )
RETURN
    DATEDIFF(currINIDate,[DATE],DAY)
```

Comment: Use `ALLEXCEPT` instead of storing `FILED_ID` in a variable.

Comment: @Marcus you are right - it's possible to use a different syntax, but as for me this one is easier to understand.

Comment: It works , thanks a lot , but if you have time can you explain the dax code please because i did'nt get all the things around

Kind Regards

Comment: Thank you for scoring. Comments just added. If you needed further commenting, please ask.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Everything is clear

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
IF(
   name of table[LIB]="INI"  
   ,DATEDIFF(
       name of table[DATE]
      ,DATE(2022,02,19)
      ,DAY
   )
   ,IF(
        name of table[LIB]="C"
        ,DATEDIFF(
            name of table[DATE]
            ,DATE(2022,02,21)
            ,DAY
         )
        ,BLANK()
    )
)
```

Waiting your answer... :)

Regards

Comment: thanks for response but it doesn't work cause there is many scenario your code doesn't take
Thanks

Comment: I didn't see the scenario for letter B, but just add a new if within code and edit letters between " " and date with your date
here the code with letter B scenario:
IF(name of table[LIB]="INI",DATEDIFF(name of table[DATE],DATE(2022,02,19),DAY), IF(name of table[LIB]="C",DATEDIFF(name of table[DATE],DATE(2022,02,21),DAY),
IF(name of table[LIB]="B",DATEDIFF(name of table[DATE],DATE(2022,02,22),DAY),
BLANK())))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).